# could .NET regular expression include '\n'?

Tags: c#, regex

i have xml-like format file.

and i need 3 information from each component.(time, classname, content)

```
<Sync Start=25199><P Class=ENCC>
foo
<Sync Start=26522><P Class=ENCC>
bar
<Sync Start=27863><P Class=ENCC>
stack
<Sync Start=30087><P Class=ENCC>
overflow
```

in this case, the result should be 4 set of information including {25199,ENCC,foo}

```
Regex exp = new Regex(@"<Sync Start=(.*?)><P Class=(.*?)>(.*?)", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
MatchCollection MatchList = exp.Matches(text);
foreach (Match FirstMatch in MatchList){
    GroupCollection groups = FirstMatch.Groups;
    foreach(Group g in groups){
        Console.WriteLine(g.Value);
    }
}
```

this prints time,classname. except content.

Please share your experiences and knowledge.

Comment: Please edit your code so that it actually compiles - `groups` doesn't exist as a variable, and `print` isn't a normal method. A short but complete program demonstrating the problem is very helpful - we should be able to copy, paste, compile and run.

Comment: First of all, C# has no support for regular expressions. The `Regex` class you're using is the _.NET_ Regex class. Also, do not use regular expressions to parse XML. It doesn't work in many cases. Finally, your XML is not well-formed. You have open tags which are not closed.

Comment: sorry for poor questions. i edited code. that format is not well known called "SAMI". i have to use that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this pattern:

```
(?m)^<Sync Start=([^>]+)><P Class=([^>]+)>\s*^([^<]\S+)
```

In [the regex demo](http://regex101.com/r/dP1aZ8/26), see the Group captures in **the right pane**.

**Sample Code**

We need to retrieve the matches from Groups 1, 2 and 3.

```
var myRegex = new Regex(@"(?m)^<Sync Start=([^>]+)><P Class=([^>]+)>\s*^([^<]\S+)");
Match matchResult = myRegex.Match(yourString);
while (matchResult.Success) {
    Console.WriteLine(matchResult.Groups[1].Value,
                      matchResult.Groups[2].Value,
                      matchResult.Groups[3].Value);
    // Add them to whatever data structure you like
    matchResult = matchResult.NextMatch();
}
```

**Explanation**

- `(?m)` turns on multi-line mode, allowing `^` and `$` to match on each line
- The `^` anchor asserts that we are at the beginning of the line
- `<Sync Start=` matches literal chars
- `([^>]+)` matches any char that is not `>`
- `><P Class=`  matches literal chars
- `([^>]+)` matches any char that is not `>`
- `>`  matches literal char
- `\s*` matches any white-space, including line breaks
- The `^` anchor asserts that we are at the beginning of the line
- `([^<]\S+)` matches a char that is not `<`, then any non-whitespace char

Comment: This one doesn't really work. You should have 4 matches, but only have three.

Answer (score 1):

The below regex would capture all the above mentioned three values from the four lines,

```
/<Sync Start=(.*?)><P Class=(.*?)>\n(\w+)/gm
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/yG5tF7/3)

C# code would be,

```
String input = @"<Sync Start=25199><P Class=ENCC>
foo
<Sync Start=26522><P Class=ENCC>
bar
<Sync Start=27863><P Class=ENCC>
stack
<Sync Start=30087><P Class=ENCC>
overflow";
Regex rgx = new Regex(@"(?m)<Sync Start=(.*?)><P Class=(.*?)>\n(\w+)");
foreach (Match m in rgx.Matches(input))
{
Console.WriteLine(m.Groups[1].Value);
Console.WriteLine(m.Groups[2].Value);
Console.WriteLine(m.Groups[3].Value);
 }
```

[IDEONE](http://ideone.com/fHr0lb)

**Explanation:**

- `<Sync Start=(.*?)>` Captures all the characters which are just after to `<Sync Start=` upto the next `>` symbol.
- `<P Class=(.*?)` Captures all the characters which are just after to the string `<P class=` upto the next `>` symbol.
- `(?m)` Multiline modifier.
- `\n(\w+)` word characters after the new line symbol are captured into group3.

Answer (score 0):

### The direct answer to your question

**Yes** it can contain a newline character as long as you set `RegexOptions.Multiline` when constructing your regular expression instance.

Comment: All `Multiline` mode does is change the behavior of the anchors (`^` and `$`), as described in [the accepted answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24880194/20938).  You may be thinking of `Singleline` mode, which allows `.` to match linefeeds, but that's no use here either; the third `(.*?)` in the OP's regex would still match nothing, and a greedy `(.*)` would match way too much.  But you can always match text with linefeeds in it, no modifiers needed.  In this case, all you have to do is change the third `(.*?)` to `([^<>]*)`.